# I there a way to remove array and dtype

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Code :

```
import requests
import multiprocessing
import simplejson as json
import numpy
from datetime import datetime

nowdate = datetime.today().date()

y = nowdate.day
arr = [0 for x in range(81)]
for x in range(1,y + 1):
   fdom = str(nowdate.replace(day=x))
   url = "https://api.opap.gr/draws/v3.0/1100/draw-date/"+fdom+"/"+fdom
   r = requests.get(url)
   d = r.json()
   for i in range(10):
      for j in range(20):
         k = d['content'][i]['winningNumbers']['list'][j]
         arr[k] += 1
   maxelmnt = numpy.where(arr == numpy.amax(arr))
   print("Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις",fdom,"είναι",maxelmnt)
   print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
   for rty in range(81):
      arr[rty] = 0
   maxint = 0
```

Output:

```
Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις 2021-02-01 είναι (array([80], dtype=int64),)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις 2021-02-02 είναι (array([61], dtype=int64),)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις 2021-02-03 είναι (array([36, 65], dtype=int64),)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις 2021-02-04 είναι (array([44], dtype=int64),)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις 2021-02-05 είναι (array([17, 23, 39, 42, 45], dtype=int64),)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις 2021-02-06 είναι (array([52, 76], dtype=int64),)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις 2021-02-07 είναι (array([17, 18, 43, 44], dtype=int64),)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις 2021-02-08 είναι (array([ 8,  9, 40, 58, 64, 77], dtype=int64),)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις 2021-02-09 είναι (array([39], dtype=int64),)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις 2021-02-10 είναι (array([44, 68], dtype=int64),)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις 2021-02-11 είναι (array([35], dtype=int64),)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις 2021-02-12 είναι (array([14], dtype=int64),)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have this code witch takes json data from a gambling game in my country finds which is the winning number that appears more often from the first day of the month up until the time you execute the code and my question is, is it possible to remove the array and dtype=int64 from the output to beautify it or not?

> I want the output to look like this:

```
Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις 2021-02-01 είναι 80
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις 2021-02-02 είναι 61
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις 2021-02-03 είναι 36, 65
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις 2021-02-04 είναι 44
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις 2021-02-05 είναι 17, 23, 39, 42, 45
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις 2021-02-06 είναι 52, 76
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις 2021-02-07 είναι 17, 18, 43, 44
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις 2021-02-08 είναι 8,  9, 40, 58, 64, 77
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις 2021-02-09 είναι 39
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις 2021-02-10 είναι 44, 68
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις 2021-02-11 είναι 35
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ο/Οι αριθμός/οί που εμφανίστικε/καν τις περισσότερες φορές στις 2021-02-12 είναι 14
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use C-style format strings in pythons `print()`. For example:

```
print("awdaadawdawd",[1,2,3],"bla %s" % (np.array([1,2,3])))
```

prints

```
awdaadawdawd [1, 2, 3] bla [1 2 3]
```

Note the syntax is

```
"some string %s" % (someVariable)
              ^
         format specifier
```

Edit:
For your output you can do

```
print("awdaadawdawd",[1,2,3],"bla %s" % (“, “.join(np.array([1,2,3]))))
```

Comment: Sorry but this wasn't what i needed i updated the question to be more specific

Answer (score -1):

Examine `maxelmnt = numpy.where(arr == numpy.amax(arr))`.  In this use of `where`, the result is a tuple, one array element for each dimension of that condition.

```
(array([14], dtype=int64),)
```

is the string display one such tuple  (a one element tuple).

```
maxelmnt = numpy.where(arr == numpy.amax(arr))[0]
```

pulls that array out of the tuple

```
In [260]: print('astring', (np.array([1,3]),))
astring (array([1, 3]),)
In [261]: print('astring', (np.array([1,3]),)[0])
astring [1 3]
```

or for a more list like display:

```
In [264]: print('astring', (np.array([1,3]),)[0].tolist())
astring [1, 3]
```

To get rid of the `[]`, we need to convert to string and use `join`:

```
In [266]: print('astring', ' ,'.join((np.array([1,3]),)[0].astype('U3')))
astring 1 ,3
```